# Summarize data table individually for multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to summarize data across multiple columns automatically if at all possible rather than writing code for each column  independently. I would like to summarize this:

```
Patch    Size       Achmil  Aciarv   Aegpod Agrcap
  A       10            0       1      1      0
  B       2             1       0      0      0
  C       2             1       0      0      0
  D       2             1       0      0      0
```

into this

```
Species   Presence      MaxSize    MeanSize    Count
Achmil       0             10         10         1
Achmil       1             2           2         3
Aciarv       0             2           2         3
Aciarv       1             10          10        1
```

I know that I can individually run group_by and summarize for each column

```
achmil<-group_by(LimitArea, Achmil) %>%
  summarise(SumA=mean(Size))
```

but is there no way to automatically run this for each column for each presence and absence using some sort of loop? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try to use `lapply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps we need to `gather` in to long format and then do the `summarise`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df1, Species, Presence, Achmil:Agrcap) %>% 
      group_by(Species, Presence)  %>% 
      summarise( MaxSize = max(Size), MeanSize = mean(Size), Count = n())
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups: Species [?]
#  Species Presence MaxSize MeanSize Count
#  <chr>      <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#1 Achmil         0   10.0     10.0      1
#2 Achmil         1    2.00     2.00     3
#3 Aciarv         0    2.00     2.00     3
#4 Aciarv         1   10.0     10.0      1
#5 Aegpod         0    2.00     2.00     3
#6 Aegpod         1   10.0     10.0      1
#7 Agrcap         0   10.0      4.00     4
```

---

In the newer version of `dplyr/tidyr`, we can use `pivot_longer`

```
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = Achmil:Agrcap, names_to = "Species",
              values_to = "Presence") %>%
   group_by(Species, Presence) %>% 
   summarise(MaxSize = max(Size), MeanSize = mean(Size), Count = n())
```

Comment: Of course! Thank you so much. Was rather silly of me to forget to first gather the data out of long form. Was too busy thinking of some loop... quite embarrassing

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution using aggregate (and `reshape2::melt()`)

```
library(reshape2)

df = melt(df[,2:ncol(df)], "Size")
aggregate(. ~ `variable`+`value`, data = df, 
          FUN = function(x) c(max = max(x), mean = mean(x), count = length(x)))

    variable value Size.max Size.mean Size.count
1   Achmil     0       10        10          1
2   Aciarv     0        2         2          3
3   Aegpod     0        2         2          3
4   Agrcap     0       10         4          4
5   Achmil     1        2         2          3
6   Aciarv     1       10        10          1
7   Aegpod     1       10        10          1
```